# Java Maven: Configuring GCP Secret Manager. Type Not Accessible Error, Multiple Module Error, and ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

I want to add the Google Cloud Platform to my Java application (https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/reference/libraries). I added dependencies to my `pom.xml` file as instructed:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
      <version>26.23.0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-secretmanager</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

And added the module to my `module-info.java` file:

```
requires google.cloud.secretmanager;
```

Issue #1: Type Not Accessible Error

When I import classes, as instructed:

```
import com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.AccessSecretVersionResponse;
import com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.ProjectName;
import com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.Replication;
import com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.Secret;
import com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.SecretManagerServiceClient; //works
import com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.SecretPayload;
import com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.SecretVersion;
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;
```

Only the `import com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.SecretManagerServiceClient;` imports successfully, all of the other classes do not, giving me error: `The type com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.ListSecretsRequest is not accessible)`.

Issue #2: ClassNotFoundException

As I tried to compile the code, using the VSCode debugger

```
'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-21.0.1.12-hotspot\bin\java.exe' '-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=localhost:63218' '@C:\Users\phill\AppData\Local\Temp\cp_4rjb4t8mfd73pngxbgeub8e7.argfile' '-m' 'NTagJavaSampleApp/com.sample.ntag.Main'
```

It started giving me compilation errors, such as:

```
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
        The type com.google.api.gax.core.BackgroundResource cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required type com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.SecretManagerServiceClient
        The resource type SecretManagerServiceClient does not implement java.lang.AutoCloseable
```

Which prompted me to install:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>gax</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And add:

```
requires gax;
```

And gave the error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.ListSecretsRequest
```

Issue #3: Multiple Module Error

It turns out, the `google.cloud.secretmanager-2.24.0.jar` file contains the `com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.SecretManagerServiceClient` class (which is needed for the initializing the client), but not the `com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.ListSecretsRequest` class, which also declares the package `package com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1` but is found in the `proto-google-cloud-secretmanager-v1-2.24.0.jar` file.

So, I installed that (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api.grpc/proto-google-cloud-secretmanager-v1):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api.grpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>proto-google-cloud-secretmanager-v1</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And added it:

```
requires proto.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1;
```

But now, when I try to import from any class from `com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1`, (such as to initialize the client: import com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.SecretManagerServiceClient;
), it gives the error `The package com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1 is accessible from more than one module: google.cloud.secretmanager, proto.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1Java(8390063)`. I feel like it's trying to take me through a web of "inner dependencies", accessing deeply nested libraries that should only be called on by higher libraries. However, I'm having trouble importing the right classes, since the packages are dispersed between multiple jar files.

FYI, I went down the rabbit hole of these errors, and ended up installing:

```
<groupId>com.google.api.grpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>proto-google-common-protos</artifactId>
    <version>2.28.0</version>
   </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
 </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>gax</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
  <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
  <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
  <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency> <!-- necessary for Java 9+ -->
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
  <artifactId>annotations-api</artifactId>
  <version>6.0.53</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And adding:

```
    requires com.google.api.apicommon;
    requires protobuf.java;
    requires grpc.protobuf;
    requires grpc.stub;
    requires annotations.api;
    requires gax;
    requires gax.grpc;
```

But I doubt that's the right way of doing it.

Comment: It should work out of the box. Can you share your code and not only your dependency management?